# Magento _getUrl call function is duplicating the url to my link

Tags: magento

I use the function `_getUrl` to link the top link I created in my custom module, but for some reason it duplicates the URL. For example, say I want it to link me to:

```
www.localhost.com/magento/sapna/account/index
```

instead, it shows:

```
www.localhost.com/magento/http://index/www.localhost.com/magentosapna/account/index
```

Here is my function:

```
const ROUTE_FORM = 'sapna/account/index';
 /**
 * Retrieve goomer/breeder registariion url
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLoginUrl(){
    return $this->_getUrl(self::ROUTE_FORM, $this->getLoginUrlParams());
}
```

i'm doing in module/Helper/Data.php and i use getUrl it does not work

I wrote this in the Data.php helper file. Can anyone help? I have been through this so many times, but I do not see what is wrong.

Comment: Can you please give more info? Where are you doing it (model/controller/block/helper)? Why aren't you just using `getUrl()`? At least give us your Magento version :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check your customer.xml file for the following :

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
            <label>Log In</label>
            <url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/>
            <title>Log In</title>
            <prepare/>
            <urlParams/>
            <position>100</position>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <remove name="reorder"></remove>
</customer_logged_out>

/* Use <prepare/> instead of <prepare>true</prepare> */
```

worked for me...!